# Retrieve requestcode from alarm broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am sending a request code through this to an alarm manager

```
 Intent broadcast_intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, rowId,  broadcast_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

I was wondering, that in the broadcastreceiver, how  can I retreive the requestcode (rowId) that I used to setup pendingIntent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for the same thing. One way would be to pass requestcode as extra in your Intent.

```
intent.putExtra("requestcode", rowId);
```

**However**, if the app is killed there is no way to retrieve the data passed by the Intent.

So you need to pass rowId as an URI , and use Intent Filter.

Comment: If the app is killed, the alarm would still be regsitered. So upon expiry you will still be able to get the requets code no?

Comment: Nope , the alarm is still registered but the extra data contained by the Intent will be lost. I tried it.

Comment: ahh I see, any explaination to why is that

Comment: Incorrect. If app is killed, the extra data is still there

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent broadcast_intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, rowId,
                              broadcast_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                              );
```

Best would be to pass the extras while referring broadcast_intent    within `getBroadcast() -    broadcast_intent.putExtras("REQUESTCODE",rowId) ;` as follows :

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, rowId,
                              broadcast_intent.putExtras("REQUESTCODE",rowId), 
                              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 3):

The requestCode used when creating a pendingIntent is not intended to pass on to the receiver, it is intended as a way for the app creating the pendingIntent to be able to manage multiple pendingIntents.

Suppose an alarm app needed to create several pendingIntents, and later needs to cancel or modify one of them.  The requestCode is used to identify which one to cancel/modify.

To pass data on, use the putExtra as described above.  Note you might very well want to use RowId for both the requestCode and the Extra data.